# magento 2: I want display a image in the module template phtml file

Tags: magento-2.0, phtml

I want to display an image in the module template file. When somebody installs my module, he can see that image. Can I store my images inside my module directory or not?

Comment: Ohoo ankush bhai magento2

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes you can store images in your module web directories depending on the area of your templates.
The path is:
**Vendor/Module/view/{frontend|adminhtml}/web/images/**

Then in your *.phtml files you can display the image:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

Comment: If I want that url in helper how can I get it? or in js file ?

Comment: In helper you can inject `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` class in your constructor as `$pageFactory` and then call `$pageFactory->getViewFileUrl()` method. For js files I have no idea how you can get it.

Answer (score 1):

I like to base-64 encode my PNG's and inline them. I use https://www.base64-image.de.

```
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ....=">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    <?php /* this defines the target of the widget */ ?>
    "#target_id": {
        <?php /* this defines the widget */ ?>
        "image.widget.name": {
            "imagename" : "<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>"
        }
    }
}
```

You would use magento's widget initialization script to start your javascript with the "imagename" option defined. This initialization technique is typically done in phtml files. My code assumes your image is in Vendor/Module/view/{frontend|adminhtml}/web/images/

For more information, you can see the magento 2 documentation. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Answer (score 0):

i tried for like 2 days using url only finally solved using

getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/209547)