# Magento 2: Get image url in phtml file

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, phtml, magento2.2, image-url

I'm trying to add an image to my first module can someone tell me how I cando this I am new to **Magento**

this is phtml file

```
<h2>Hello world</h2>
```

module is in

```
app/code/Test/Helloworld
```

[image]

This is my directory structure of Helloworld Module

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: I add images like above but its not working sir. i cleared my cache but not working

Comment: What is the error or what is display in image URL?

Comment: nothing show just text

Comment: is there any other solution

Comment: @Hemal The question you are asking is already available on magento stack exchange refer this link [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124873/magento-2-i-want-display-a-image-in-the-module-template-phtml-file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124873/magento-2-i-want-display-a-image-in-the-module-template-phtml-file) & try to search for the things you wanted to do then post it as a question Thank You!

Comment: its not working thats why i asked again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example your image at:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/demo.jpg

Use `$block->getViewFileUrl()` function to get image url in phtml file like this

```
echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/demo.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Module image** : `$block->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/test.jpg');`

**Use Theme image** : `$block->getViewFileUrl('images/test.jpg');`

Answer (score 0):

If you using phtml file add an image, CSS and js use `$block->getViewFileUrl()` and if you working on block use this`{{view url="images/IMG_7300.JPG"}}`

Answer (score 0):

in case if u have enabled opcache in your php.ini u will not see immediately the result. Also the images from the module are not added into pub/static folder. therefore to clear opcache do:

`systemctl restart php<<version.minor>>-fpm`
i.e. `systemctl restart php7.4-fpm`