# How do I set scandir to list the module web/images directory

Tags: magento-2.1, php, module, template

How do I set scandir to list the module web/images directory?
getViewFileUrl generates the file path but what I need is the directory path, so scandir can read the folder contents.

**Vendor > Module > view > frontend > web**

template file:

```
<?php
    $images = scandir("images/base/thumbnails");
    $ignore = Array('.', '..');
    foreach($images as $curimg){
        if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            echo '<a href="'.$this->getViewFileUrl("Vendor_Module::images/base/full/$curimg").'"><img src="'.$this->getViewFileUrl("Vendor_Module::images/base/thumbnails/$curimg").'"></a>';
        }
    };
?>
```

Comment: Not getting your question, what you need to do ? you need image url for display in front ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your **image file** to this path

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/image.png

Now call this image in your phtml file like this

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124893/48571)

Comment: You are reffering to image.png but i'd like to know how all images from the thumbnails directory can be listed.

Answer (score 0):

You can define function in your block file :-

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template { 

    public function __construct(

       \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    ){
        $this->assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    }

    public function testImageUrl($path){
       $url =  $this->assetRepo->getUrl($path);;
       return $url;
    }
}
```

Now all in phtml file :-

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->testImageUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>
```

Comment: This calls image.png but does not list all images from the directory

Comment: Can you able to clarify your question so i can able to get more idea ?

Comment: Updated my question. Hope it is clear now

Comment: clarified the question.